# Flipping Coins Until One Head Appears in All Coins

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

- Suppose there are 10 coins : each coin has 0.5 probability of heads and 0.5 probability of tails
- Each turn, I randomly generate an integer between 0 and 10. I then randomly select those many coins (sampling without replacement)
- I then flip those coins
- I want to repeat this process until at least one head has appeared in all coins

Here is the R code I wrote for this problem (1 = head, 0 = tails, -1 = not selected):

```
  multi_coins_flip_until_first_head <- function(n) {
      count_coins <- numeric(n)
      head_seen_coins <- logical(n)
      flips_coins <- vector("list", n)
      while(any(!head_seen_coins)) {
         selected_coins <- sample(seq_len(n), sample(seq_len(n), 1))
        for (i in seq_len(n)) {
          if (i %in% selected_coins) {
            flip <- sample(c(1, 0), 1)
            count_coins[i] <- count_coins[i] + 1
            flips_coins[[i]] <- c(flips_coins[[i]], flip)
            if (flip == 1) {
              head_seen_coins[i] <- TRUE
            }
          } else {
            flips_coins[[i]] <- c(flips_coins[[i]], -1)
          }
        }
      }
      return(list("Number of Flips for First Head" = count_coins, "Sequence" = flips_coins))
    }
```

When I look at the results of this function:

```
> multi_coins_flip_until_first_head(10)
    $`Number of Flips for First Head`
     [1] 10  7  5  9  5  8  7  9  5  7
    
    $Sequence
    $Sequence[[1]]
     [1]  0 -1 -1  1 -1  0  1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1  1 -1  0  0 -1 -1 -1  1 -1
    
    $Sequence[[2]]
     [1] -1 -1  0 -1  1 -1  0 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  1
    
    $Sequence[[3]]
     [1] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1  0 -1  0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1
    
    $Sequence[[4]]
     [1]  0  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  0  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1
    
    $Sequence[[5]]
     [1] -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1
    
    $Sequence[[6]]
     [1] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  1 -1 -1  1  0 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  0
    
    $Sequence[[7]]
     [1] -1  0 -1 -1 -1  1  1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1
    
    $Sequence[[8]]
     [1]  1  0  1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  0  1 -1  0 -1 -1
    
    $Sequence[[9]]
     [1] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  0 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1
    
    $Sequence[[10]]
     [1] -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  1 -1
```

However, there are some problems I am noticing here:

- It is telling me that the first coin took 10 flips to get the first head - but when I inspect the output `Sequence[[1]]`, I can see that the first head appeared after the 4th flip.
- In the next coin, it is telling me that 7 flips are required for the first head, but the first head occurs in 5 flips
- etc.

Can someone please show me how to fix this? Specifically, can someone please show me how to correct my R code?

Comment: Are you new to R? You are not taking advantage of any of R's vectorization capabilities.

Comment: I think your code does what you want it to. Since the coins are chosen randomly, the order in which they were flipped is not the same as the order of values in the `Sequence`. In other words, the values in `Number of Flips for First Head` don't tell you which coin in the respective `Sequence` was the first successful flip, only the number of flips it took, i.e. the number of non-`-1` elements.

Comment: @ Robert Hacken: Thank you so much for your reply! I never thought of that - I will try to think of a new way to fix this

Comment: The probability of at least one coin coming up heads is just 1 - (probability of all tails). The probability of all tails is 0.5^n, if n is the number of coins. The number of tosses in any one experiment is just one more than the number of 'failures' (i.e. the number of tosses that were all tails). This can therefore be very quickly modelled by a negative binomial distribution, and you can run your experiment by doing `rnbinom(1, (n <- sample(10, 1)), 1 - 0.5^n) + 1`. If you want to run the experiment 10,000 times, you can do `replicate(10000, rnbinom(1, (n <- sample(10, 1)), 1 - 0.5^n) + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```r
throw <- function(nr_coins = 10L) {
  x <- rep(-1L, nr_coins)
  sel <- rbinom(nr_coins, 1L, .5) == 1L
  x[sel] <- rbinom(sum(sel), 1L, .5)
  x
}

simulate <- function(nr_coins = 10L) {
  has_head <- rep(FALSE, nr_coins)
  all_results <- integer(0L)
  i <- 0L
  while(!all(has_head)) {
    th <- throw(nr_coins)
    all_results <- rbind(all_results, th)
    has_head <- has_head | (th == 1L)
    i <- i + 1L
  }
  rownames(all_results) <- paste("Round", seq_len(nrow(all_results)))
  colnames(all_results) <- paste("Coin", seq_len(nr_coins))
  list(nr_throws = i, throws = all_results)
}

simulate()

## on average we need ~ 10 rounds
mean(replicate(10000, simulate()$nr_throws))
# [1] 10.6648
```

### Explanation

- `throw` simulates the random process:

  1. Select some coins `sel` (this is equivalent to simulate `nr_coins` Bernoulli random variables (`0/1`) where `1` indicates coin selected, `0` otherwise).
  2. For each of the selected coins toss it (again a Bernoulli random variable for each of the `sum(sel)` selected coins)
- `simulate` repeats this throwing exercise until each coin showed `HEAD` at least once.

*N.B.*  Letting `all_results` grow in each iteration is not the best of ideas (we would pre-allocate some space and grow only if needed, this avoids copying matrixes in each step), but is OK for this toy example. Depending on what you need, it may not even be necessary to store `all_results` at all and just count the number of rounds until the event finally occurs.

Comment: The rule `sel <- rbinom(nr_coins, 1L, .5) == 1L` does not always select a coin. This seems incorrect. This can be easily tested with a single coin, `mean(replicate(10000, simulate(nr_coins=1)$nr_throws))` which yields `4.01`.

Comment: @clp: *Each turn, I randomly generate an integer between **0** and 10. I then randomly select those many coins (sampling without replacement)* so 0 coins seem to be ok

Answer (score 1):

In `count_coins` (or in the output `Number of Flips for First Head`) you are counting the **total** number of flips because you add 1 each time the dice is flipped, even if the dice is flipped after the first 'head' has appeared. A quick fix to your code could be to add an `if` statement:

```
multi_coins_flip_until_first_head <- function(n) {
  count_coins <- numeric(n)
  head_seen_coins <- logical(n)
  flips_coins <- vector("list", n)
  while(any(!head_seen_coins)) {
    selected_coins <- sample(seq_len(n), sample(seq_len(n), 1))
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
      if (i %in% selected_coins) {
        flip <- sample(c(1, 0), 1)
        if(!(1 %in% flips_coins[[i]])){ # add this to check for previous 'head'
          count_coins[i] <- count_coins[i] + 1
        } 
        flips_coins[[i]] <- c(flips_coins[[i]], flip)
        if (flip == 1) {
          head_seen_coins[i] <- TRUE
        }
      } else {
        flips_coins[[i]] <- c(flips_coins[[i]], -1)
      }
    }
  }
  return(list("Number of Flips for First Head" = count_coins, "Sequence" = flips_coins))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Added: # of flips before first head.**

My vectorized try:

```
set.seed(20231129)                                          # initialize random sequence.
n                     <- 10                                 # number of coins.
max_tries             <- n*8                                # large number.
throws                <- c()                                # result of throws, indexed by coin, throw index (1...).
flip                  <- function() {  sample(c(1, 0), 1) }
flips                 <- rep(list(flip), n)                 # make a list of n flippers.

## Simulate coin toss.
for (i in seq(max_tries)){
  throw                 <- cbind( "throw" = rep(-1, n))     # this throw.
  dimnames(throw)[2]    <- i                                # label by throw index.
  selected_coins        <- sample(seq_len(n), sample(seq_len(n), 1))  # choose coins.
  throw[selected_coins] <- mapply(function(f) f(), flips[selected_coins]) 
  throws                <- cbind(throws, throw)             # is copied, can be optimized.
  if (min(rowSums((throws == 1) * 1)) > 0) break            # all coins are OK.
}

ones <- rowSums(throws == 1)                                # number of successes by coin.
cbind(throws, rsum = rowSums(throws == 1))                  # show throws, successes.
stopifnot(min(ones) > 0)

print(sprintf("# throws = %d, max tries = %d", i, max_tries), quote=FALSE)

## Calculate flips before first head from throws. 
throws_for_first_success <-                              # indexed by coin.
  apply(throws, 1, function(x) which(x==1) ) |>          # by row, select success indices.
  lapply(append, c(-1)) |>                               # avoid error when no success.
  sapply("[[", 1)                                        # select first element and convert list to vector.

## Alternatively.
## throws_for_first_success <- apply(throws, 1, function(x) which(x==1) )             # list of vectors containing success indices.
## throws_for_first_success[which(lengths(throws_for_first_success ) == 0)] <- c(-1)  # replace empty vector by c(-1).
## throws_for_first_success <- sapply(throws_for_first_success , "[[", 1)             # select first element and convert list to vector.

cat("Number of throws for first success\n", throws_for_first_success, '\n')
##
```

gives:

```
       1  2  3  4 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 rsum
 [1,] -1 -1  1 -1 1  0  1  1  0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  1    5
 [2,] -1 -1  1 -1 1 -1  0  1  0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  0    3
 [3,]  0 -1  0 -1 0 -1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1    6
 [4,]  0 -1 -1 -1 1  0 -1  1  0  0 -1 -1  1 -1  0    3
 [5,]  1 -1  1  1 1  0  0 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1    7
 [6,]  0 -1 -1 -1 0 -1  0 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  1    1
 [7,] -1 -1  0  1 0  0  1  0  1  0 -1 -1  0 -1  0    3
 [8,] -1  0  0 -1 0  1 -1  1  1  0 -1 -1  0 -1  0    3
 [9,]  0 -1 -1 -1 1 -1  1  0  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  1    3
[10,]  0 -1  1  0 0  0  0  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1    4
   
[1] # throws = 15

Number of throws for first success
3 3 7 5 1 15 4 6 5 3
```

**Or**, use replicate() instead of mapply() and calculate first success on the fly.

```
set.seed(20231129)                                          # initialize random sequence.
n                     <- 1E1                                # number of coins.
max_tries             <- n*8                                # large number.

## Simulate coin toss.
system.time({
throwf                  <- rep(0, n)                        # Number of throws for first success, indexed by coin.
for (i in seq(max_tries)){
  throw                 <- rep(-1, n)      # this throw.
  selected_coins        <- sample(seq_len(n), sample(seq_len(n), 1))  # choose coins.
  throw[selected_coins] <- replicate(length(selected_coins), sample(x = c(1,0), size = 1))
  throwf[(throwf == 0) & (throw == 1)] <- i                 # collect first success on the fly.
  if (min(throwf) > 0) break                                # all coins are OK.
  stopifnot(i < max_tries)
}
})
throwf
## [1]  3  3  7  5  1 15  4  6  5  3
```

Observe that this solution is (much) slower because it requires for any individual coin a call to sample() in stead of a single `rbinom(nr_coins, 1L, .5) == 1L`.

The solution is to replace `replicate(length(selected_coins), sample(x = c(1,0), size = 1))` by `sample(x = c(1,0), size = length(selected_coins), replace=TRUE)`.

See also: [Expected number of tosses till first head comes up](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136806/expected-number-of-tosses-till-first-head-comes-up).